ImportError: libgridstore.so.0 when importing GridDB in Python3.10
I'm trying to get GridDB working on my WSL/Ubuntu environment. I have followed https://pypi.org/project/griddb-python/ to install griddb and was successful but when trying to import the module I'm getting the following error:
(griddb-env) lockmorei@LOCKMOREI:~$ python3.10 -c "import griddb_python"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lockmorei/griddb-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/griddb_python.py", line 21, in <module>
    import _griddb_python
ImportError: libgridstore.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I think what's happening is that GridDB is using shared library as part of the c_client. However, even after installing it, I'm getting the same error.
Using https://github.com/griddb/c_client and latest 5.7.0 version:
wget https://github.com/griddb/griddb/releases/download/v5.7.0/gridstore_5.7.0_ubuntu22.04_x86_64.deb
sudo dpkg -i griddb_5.7.0_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f

Installed correctly I think:
lockmorei@LOCKMOREI:~$ sudo dpkg -i griddb_5.7.0_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 49718 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack griddb_5.7.0_amd64.deb ...
Removed "/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gridstore.service".

------------------------------------------------------------
Information:
  User and group have already been registered correctly.
  GridDB uses existing user and group.
------------------------------------------------------------

Unpacking griddb (5.7.0) over (5.7.0) ...
Setting up griddb (5.7.0) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gridstore.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/gridstore.service.

Updated correctly I think:
lockmorei@LOCKMOREI:\~$ sudo apt-get install -f
\[sudo\] password for lockmorei:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

Running the below command, I don't understand why the 'libgridstore.so.0 file is not being added when I install the c_client.
lockmorei@LOCKMOREI:~/griddb-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages$ ldd /home/lockmorei/griddb-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_griddb_python.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so*
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc40b8f000)
        librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3af583e000)
        libgridstore.so.0 => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3af55bb000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3af54d2000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3af54a4000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3af5290000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3af58aa000)

I also tried ldconfig -p | grep libgridstore and no output. No matter what I do to change the paths or install the dependencies, I'm still getting the same libgridstore file not found error. Any idea how that file can be added correctly?
Specs:
   griddb_python: 0.8.5
          Python: 3.10
  Virtualization: wsl
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.167.4-microsoft-standard-WSL2
    Architecture: x86-64

